# Triple flute drill bits Vs. 2 flute drill bits

Tags: drill-bits

I have found some triple flute drill bits and am wondering if they are any better than the double flute. I would think they make cleaner cuts but am sure there is some bad things that go along with it. Anything about this is helpful.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that as far as woodworking goes a 3-flute bit is an answer to a question nobody asked. We already have multiple bits we can use to drill all sorts of holes, and if the "cleaner cuts" thing is the primary advantage supposed for a triple-fluted bit I'd have to ask, compared to what? A double-flute bit of the same type or a lip-and-spur bit or as traditional auger? Even comparing standard twist bits cutting performance and how crisp the entry hole is will vary with bit quality *and how the tip is ground* — most twist bits used by woodworkers are NOT dedicated wood bits.

Answer (score 4):

They cut faster and cleaner. Negatives that I know of is cost (they are more expensive) and heat. They will heat up quicker because there is less steel there. Too much heat and your bit is dead.